# How do I extract values out of a DataStreamSource of type class in using Flink in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this class

```
case class SummaryWithType(summaryType: String, payload: JsonObject)
```

Which is used here

```
val kinesis = new FlinkKinesisConsumer[SummaryWithType](
  "kinesis-stream", new SummaryDeserializationSchema, consumerConfig)

val stream = env.addSource(kinesis)
stream.print()
```

`stream` is of type `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource[SummaryWithType]`

How do I extract `summaryWithType` from the `stream` object so that I can perform logic on it?

Comment: This is a DataStream. It is a collection of (distributed) data. Since the logic you want to apply needs to be applied to every partition, you need to tell Flink what to apply and it will do it for you. You can not just extract the data and do with it as you please (technically you can use `DataStreamUtils.collect` but don't. It's a bad idea outside of testing) You can use functions such as `map`, `filter` etc. to transform your data. Please read the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to ```map``` or ```filter``` the data based on whatever the value of ```summaryType``` is.

Comment: You can pattern match on the `summaryType` both of those are higher order functions. They take a function that is `SummaryWithType => R`, You can pass in your logic as an argument

Comment: Hey thanks for being really helpful. I think I have found the solution I'm looking for. I'll write an answer to this question when I'm done

Comment: I am glad. Even happier that you were able to get there on your own without requiring someone to give you the working code.

Comment: There's some tutorial content here -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/ -- that you may find helpful.